# ffmpeg пакетное удаление мр3 файлов

Tags: ffmpeg

Делаю пакетное сведение файлов (в одной папке находятся 30 файлов .mp3 и один файл input.mp4):

```
FOR %%f IN (*.mp3) DO ffmpeg.exe -i "%%f" -i "input.mp4" -acodec copy -vcodec copy "%%~nf.mp4"
```

как сделать так, чтобы ffmpeg после пакетной обработки удалил все аудио файлы...пробовал дописывать в батник: del FOR %%f IN (*.mp3) ffmpeg их не видит...

Answer (score 0):

отвечу сам, может кому пригодится:

```
FOR %%f IN (*.mp3) DO ffmpeg.exe -i "%%f" -i "input.mp4" -acodec copy -vcodec copy "%%~nf.mp4"
del *.mp3
```